# javascript function on event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm trying to write a web page that include a list that add an item when the something happen in the server side.
I have a function with the information in my controller, but I don't understand how to "active" the JavaScript to ask for the information (or to send from the server side to the java)

That the function in the controller:

```
private void Client_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            ///update the javascript....
        }
```

Comment: polling, long polling, or web sockets

Comment: You should use Signalr.

Comment: For sockets you could use SignalR. Try a Google search on that and you'll find a chatbox with that.

Comment: I can't use ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical website is one way communication. which means, that browser requests the content, display it after when necessary browser requests additional information and update UI.

For doing the opposite there are this options.

- Poling - browser send requests (AJAX) and checks if there are updates for him from time to time, and update... for simple scenarios this should be enough
- Modern Browsers support [websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which allows to open 2 way communication, and push data back from server
- My preferred way is to use libraries like [SignalR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignalR) which gives ability to send 2 way notification without thinking about internal implementation details...SignalR decides what to use - polling or websocket, based on browser it is executing

Comment: np, hope post is helpful... welcome to stackoverflow )